# Why are silyl chlorides more readily hydrolysed than alkyl chlorides?

Tags: reactivity, hydrolysis, organosilicon-compounds

I know that the $\ce{Si-Cl}$ bond has a slightly higher energy, but silyl chlorides are much more readily hydrolyzed compared to alkyl chlorides. I do not fully understand why that is. My thoughts so far are:

- There is a better match in energy between the orbitals of the $\ce{Si-Cl}$ bond and water.
- Reactions proceed when there is a favorable interaction between HOMO and LUMO.
- In this case, the HOMO is the lone pair on the water molecule. The LUMO of a $\ce{Si-Cl}$ bond is closer to it in energy compared to a $\ce{C-Cl}$ bond.

Is this the right argument to take?

Answer (score 4):

Using $\ce{CCl4}$ and $\ce{SiCl4}$ as the basis for comparison, there are several reasons.

1. The greater electronegativity difference between Si and Cl leads to a larger $\delta^+$ on silicon, making it more electrophilic and susceptible to attack by water.
2. Larger size of Si means that there is less steric hindrance towards the approach of water.
3. It is *possible* that the hydrolysis of $\ce{SiCl4}$ proceeds via an alternative, faster pathway that involves a five-coordinate intermediate (as opposed to $\ce{CCl4}$, in which five-coordinate carbon does not occur).